# Launching Android Studio from Terminal

Tags: 14.04, android, android-studio

I've downloaded and installed Android Studio and also added the path to my .bashrc

```
export PATH="~/android-studio/bin/:$PATH"
```

What I'm looking at now is that one command which will launch android studio from anywhere in the Ubuntu file system.
For example if I type subl or atom anywhere it opens up the respective editor. Can something like that be done here?

Comment: There's a mistake in that. If you wrap `~` in quotes, it won't get expanded to your home directory. Use `$HOME` instead, or keep the `~` outside the quotes. Test with `echo $PATH`.

Answer (score 6):

Actually I figured it out. Just created this sym link

```
sudo ln -s ~/android-studio/bin/studio.sh /usr/local/bin/studio
```

Now typing the word studio would launch Android Studio from anywhere on the file system.

Comment: `studio.sh` will also work if you set the path correctly as described by [@muru's comment](http://askubuntu.com/questions/578387/launching-android-studio-from-terminal#comment798872_578387).